# How do I access state across multiple Contexts if I only have a single Provider in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I was going over the updated Stephen Girder react-native course and saw that he used a single createDataContext file so that his Reducer has access to Context and Provider.

his createDataContext file looks like this:

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, initialState) => {
  const Context = React.createContext(reducer, initialState);
  console.log('show me the initial state: ', initialState)
  // actions === {addBlogPost: (dispatch) => { return ()=> {} }}
  const Provider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const boundActions = {};
    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };
  return {Context, Provider};
};
```

BlogPostContext

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';

const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log('show me the state inside the reducer: ', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add_blogpost':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
          title: action.payload.title,
          content: action.payload.content,
        },
      ];
    case 'delete_blogpost':
      return state.filter(blogPost => blogPost.id !== action.payload);
    case 'edit_blogpost':
      return state.map(blogPost => {
        return blogPost.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : blogPost;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};



const addBlogPost = dispatch => {
  return (title, content, callback) => {
    console.log("inside addBlogpost", title, content);
    dispatch({
      type: "add_blogpost",
      payload: { title, content }
    });
    callback();
  };
};

const deleteBlogPost = dispatch => {
  return id => {
    dispatch({type: 'delete_blogpost', payload: id});
  };
};


const editBlogPost = dispatch => {
  return (id, title, content) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "edit_blogpost",
      payload: { id, title, content }
    });
  };
};

export const {Context, Provider} = createDataContext(
  blogReducer,
  {addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost, editBlogPost},
  [],
);
```

Methods that need to be accessed on a particular page are simply de-destructured on the page that they're needed:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Context} from '../context/BlogContext';
import BlogPostForm from '../components/BlogPostForm';

const CreateScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {addBlogPost} = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <BlogPostForm
      onSubmit={(title, content) => {
        addBlogPost(title, content, () => navigation.navigate('Homepage'));
      }}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default CreateScreen;
```

I would like to create a second Context page that contains a different reducer, methods, and most importantly initialState object.

However, I will NOT be able to access the state of the second Context page because in the createDataContext only passes state as a value to a provider.

```
<Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
```

That only grants me access to the first Context(BlogContext).  How can I access the state of the second Context page given how createDataContext file is at the moment?  Would I need to create a second createDataContext or do I need to define individual states when I pass the state in the Context.Provider?